# Fill multiple elements with a single jQuery Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, validation

I have this form that validates the fields on submit through ajax (using Codeigniter's Form_Validation Class).

```
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1"> />
<span id="field1_error"></span> 
....
<input type="text" name="field2" id="field2"> />
<span id="field2_error"></span> 
...
<input type="text" name="field3" id="field3"> />
<span id="field3_error"></span> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="btnPublish" />
```

On submit, jQuery calls CI's validation method. Which would be the best way to output those validation errors with a single Ajax Call?

Comment: What's the benefit of using AJAX here? If I get it right, you are using server-side validation of the entire form on-submit. How does it differ from actually submitting the page and displaying validation output generated by the server along with the form?

Comment: The reason is that I'm displaying additional fields based on the selection of a dropdown. If I submit the page normally, those fields are lost. I believe its far more difficult to solve this, than the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this approach can help you.. its more like a hint than complete solution...

On server side you will do validation and return JSON (for example) 
- **$progress** is true/false - depending on validation result and **$errors** is array(name,translated_error/ or "")

**partial php:**

```
$res = array(
    'progress' => $progress,
    'errors' => $errors
);
$jsonReturn = json_encode($res);

//output result
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');       
echo $jsonReturn;
```

**partial jQuery:**

```
var errorFields = $([]).add(field1_error).add(field2_error).add(field3_error),
    mainFields = $([]).add(field1).add(field2).add(field3);

$('#btnPublish').button().click(function(event){

    mainFields.removeClass('ui-state-error');
    errorFields.val();                                                  

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: your_url,
    data: $('#your_form_id').serialize(),
        async: false,
        success: function (returned_value){
            var obj = $.parseJSON(returned_value);

            if (obj.progress==true){
                alert('Validation successfull');

            }else{
                $.each(obj.errors, function(index, value) { 
                    if (value!=""){ //it will skip those fields with no errors
                        $('#'+index).addClass(('ui-state-error'));
                        $('#'+index+'_error').val(value);
                    }
                });

            }//end return ajax

        }//end ajax
    });         

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works great! Indeed, JSON solves a lot of problems, however I'm concerned about security. Since, the JS code is available to the end-user, how to ensure that it cannot be manipulated to do other things (automated requests, request large data sets)?

Comment: There is always some kind of concern when you use anything that is publicly available. Ajax (JavaScript) is not exception to that rule, but than you have to ask yourself: Am I using it correctly and do I give lot of freedom to my users just for the sake of better user experience. And of course Internet is full of good examples how to avoid some of your concerns. I know that this is kind of generic answer to your question but simply thats the fact.
Security is in you hand (code). Lack of it is also.